# Int (or short) to byte array using Big endian

Tags: javascript, arrays, endianness

I'm trying to make universal functions to convert integers, shorts and others to byte arrays and vice versa, all using pre-defined byte count per value.

The encoding function seems to be correct. It looks like this:

```
  /**Parameters:
     data - string, every `bytes` bytes will form one number entry
     array - the output array refference where numbers will be put
     bytes - number of bytes per entry
     big_endian - use big endian? (little endian otherwise)
  */
  function fromBytes(data, array, bytes, big_endian) {
    //Temporary variable for current number
    var num;
    //Loop through byte array
    for(var i=0, l=data.length; i<l; i+=bytes) {
      num=0;
      //Jump through the `bytes` and add them to number
      if(big_endian) {
        for(var b=0; b<bytes; b++) {
          num+=(num << 8)+data.charCodeAt(i+b);
        }
      }
      else {
        for(var b=bytes-1; b>=0; b--) {
          num+=(num << 8)+data.charCodeAt(i+b);
        }
      }
      //Add decomposed number to an array
      array.push(num);
    }
    return array;
  }
```

<sup>If there is something wrong please tell me.</sup>

Now, the encoding function seems easy for little endian - I just take `number%255` and then divide the number by 255 (and repeat that).
But I'm not sure how to encode number in big endian - how to get the largest part first?

Here's my function with the missing part:

```
  /**Parameters:
     array - arrau of numbers to encode
     bytes - number of bytes per entry
     big_endian - use big endian? (little endian otherwise)
  */
function toBytes(array, bytes, big_endian) {

    //The produced string
    var data = "";
    //last retrieved number
    var num;
    //Loop through byte array
    for(var i=0, l=array.length; i<l; i++) {
      num = array[i];
      if(big_endian) {
        /** ??? **/
      }
      else {
        for(var b=bytes-1; b>=0; b--) {
          data+=String.fromCharCode(num%255);
          num = Math.floor(num/255);
        }      
      }
      //Add decomposed number to an array
      array.push(num);
    }
    return array;
  }
```

The little endian conversion works. Could you give me a clue how to encode int, short or double to 4, 2 or 8 bytes using Big endian?

Comment: you can simple reverse array with little endian

Comment: That would require: 1. create an array, 2. put bytes in it, 3. reverse it, 4. Put it in the string. I need to be effective here. I'm sure there is purely mathematical solution.

Comment: can you provide sample input and sample output for your functions?